# git log doesn't show modified submodules of a commit

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-log

With git, is it possible to show modified submodules of a commit when execute `git log` in a master repo managing submodule ?
I try differents values for --pretty and --submodule options but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, `git show` seems to be done for this. For exemple :

```
git show commit_name --name-only
```